# Are non-linear extensions to QM equivalent to time travel?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, wavefunction-collapse, non-linear-systems, time-travel

I recently learned of the existence of Objective Collapse theories which add non-linear terms to QM to explain wave function collapse. Per the 2014 paper [Treating Time Travel Quantum Mechanically](https://arxiv.org/abs/1401.4933), the existence of closed timelike loops induces non-linear behavior. Given the two-way equivalence between time travel and faster-than-light travel, I wonder if this implication between time travel and quantum non-linearity is also two-way: given that time travel implies non-linearity, do Objective Collapse theories that posit non-linear extensions to QM also imply the existence of time travel (and by extension, FTL communication)?

The fact that [time travel](https://web.archive.org/web/20090129114503/http://www.frc.ri.cmu.edu/users/hpm/project.archive/general.articles/1991/TempComp.html) and [Nonlinear quantum mechanics](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9801041) both imply polynomial-time solutions for NP-complete problems gives me further reason to suspect that there may be a two-way equivalence here, but I can't say I really understand that non-linear quantum computing paper, so perhaps this is just a complete coincidence.